# web service pointing to 2 classes

Tags: c#, web-services

I could have sworn I saw this done somewhere, but I guess maybe it was a DLL, not a web service.  I was originally doing this as a DLL, but now need to use a web service.

I have a service file (DataService.svc).  I have class Foo and class Bar.  Both have the same methods (Load, LoadAll, Insert, Update).  I know that a web service doesn't support overloading, but I thought that since these were in separate classes it might be possible.  Is there a way to configure this so that in my client, I could do this:

```
DataService.Foo.Load();
```

or

```
DataService.Bar.Load();
```

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Method overloading is supported by webservice. you need to use MessageName property of WebMethod attribute on the overloaded method. Like [WebMethod(MessageName = "LoadBar")]  . Remeber, MessageName     should be unique.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for.  The client would then have to call it like this:  DataService.LoadBar().  I want the client's method name to be the same, just under a different class.